# How do i teleport my game object to a specific location in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

basically what i wanted to do is to teleport my cube randomly into a specific location

sorry, i have completely no idea how do i teleport my game object into a specific location. ive tried some code, it seems to make sense for me but it still does return an error, this is my code below:

```
public Transform cubepos; //My cube position
public Transform pos1;//teleport position 1
public Transform pos2;// teleport position 2
public Transform pos3;// and so on
public Transform pos4;
public Transform pos5;
public Transform pos6;
public Transform pos7;
public Transform pos8;
public Transform pos9;
public Transform pos10;

// im pretty sure that i dont need to create a variable to reference each of my 
teleport position for my cube, maybe some of you guys could tell me what should i do so 
i can go into the specific teleport location without having to make a variable for each 
teleport location...?


void Update()
{
    int pos = Random.Range(1, 12);

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
    {
        switch (pos)
                {
                    case i:
                        cubepos.position = // how do i set my cube position based on
                                           the pos that returned an integer? like if it 
                                             returns 8, i would have to set my cube 
                                            position into pos8.position and i have to 
                                             check every number, that wouldve wasted my
                                              time a lot typing that code;
                }
    }

    
}
```

Comment: where do you put the teleport positions to access it?

Comment: what error is it you see?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either have to use the variable names for everything, and then you're stuck with a `switch` case, or you can put those transforms in a `List` and access the List by index.

With the List you can do it two ways - the harder way would be to keep your code as-is, make a list, and initialize the List in Start, like:

```
// your transforms
private List<Transform> transforms;

void Start()
{
    transforms = new List<Transform>()
    {
        pos1,
        pos2,
        // ...
        pos10
    };
}
```

then you can do:

```
void Update()
{
    int pos = Random.Range(1, 12);
    cubepos.position = transforms[pos-1].position;
}
```

**Be careful here** because your `Random.Range` is 1 to 12 but you only have the 10 transforms, so I'd expect you to get an out-of-range exception when you get returns on 11/12. Might be better to define it as

```
int pos = Random.Range(0, transforms.Count-1);
cubepos.position = transforms[pos].position;
```

The other easier way is to just ditch all the other transforms, `pos1`, etc., and use the list:

```
public class TransformList : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Transform> transforms = new List<Transform>();
    
    void Update()
    {
        int pos = Random.Range(0, transforms.Count-1);
        cubepos.position = transforms[pos].position;
    }
 
    // Other stuff
}
```

Once you do this you'll see your list in the Inspector window:

[image: Inspector window]

Then you can click the `>` glyph and expand it, then the `+` button to add transforms:

[image: Adding entries]

Then you can add as many as you want. By keeping the `int pos` definition linked to `transforms.Count` instead of a hard-coded value you can modify that list as you want and everything will continue to run.

[image: Full list]

Comment: I'll warn you too, like with the `Random.Range(1, 12);` business, you're doing this in the `Update()` callback, which means you're going to change the position with every frame, so 60-ish times per second your thing is going to be changing positions. I'm sure this is probably just stub code to help us understand your problem, but be sure to include some logic to not actually change position every frame!

Answer (score 0):

Replace all your transforms `pos1`-`pos10` with the array of transforms.

```
[SerializeField]
Transform[] _allPossiblePositions;
```

Add all possible positions to this array in the inspector. Then your random value will be just an index of the element in the array.

```
int index = Random.Range(0, _allPossitblePositions.Length);
Transform newPos = _allPossibleTransforms[index];

myAwesomeCubeTransform.position = newPos.position;
```

Comment: might get an index out of bounds error

Comment: @Senbazuru there was a copied and pasted typo with the `1` instead of `0`, yeah